# How to get value from another ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have a script `testSuite.rb`, which checks an excel to get the test cases to run, and runs them like:

```
if runmode == 'Y' 
  path= testcase + '.rb' 
  output = system("ruby #{path}")
  puts output
```

This always returns `true`.

In my test case script, I have a value which is set `true`/`false` (pass/fail) as per the test result. I want `testSuite.rb` script to capture that value and update the excel. How do I achieve this? How do I get a value from another ruby script? Any better method of getting values using class?

Backticks give me:

> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

error and `load path` also returns `true`.

I don't want to get dirty and write my testcase result in a file and then make testsuite read it.

Comment: Any comments on the downvotes?

Comment: `system` returns the script's exit code. Use [backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-60) to capture the script's output.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but it's not clear to me what you're trying to do here ... maybe you can clarify your question.

Comment: @Stefan: backticks give me - Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") error.

Comment: `output = \`ruby #{path}\`` should work

Comment: @Stefan - why don't you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all files are written in Ruby, you can probably `require` your test case from your test suite (or vice versa) and call the appropriate methods. However, let's assume that your test cases are arbitrary executables:

> In my test case script, I have a value which is set `true`/`false` (pass/fail) as per the test result. I want `testSuite.rb` script to capture that value ...

You could pass this value as an [exit status](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) by calling [`exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exit):

```
# passing_test.rb
exit

# failing_test.rb
exit(false)

# test_suite.rb
system('ruby passing_test.rb') #=> true
system('ruby failing_test.rb') #=> false
```

Or by printing some value to stdout (use [`` `cmd` ``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-60) to capture the output):

```
# passing_test.rb
puts 'passed'

# failing_test.rb
puts 'failed'

# test_suite.rb
`ruby passing_test.rb` #=> "passed\n"
`ruby failing_test.rb` #=> "failed\n"
```

Or a combination of both. (`$?` returns the [`Process::Status`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process/Status.html))

```
# passing_test.rb
puts 'passed'
exit

# failing_test.rb
puts 'failed'
exit(false)

# test_suite.rb
`ruby passing_test.rb` #=> "passed\n"
$?.success?            #=> true

`ruby failing_test.rb` #=> "failed\n"
$?.success?            #=> false
```

Comment: How do I pass a parameter? I am trying like path=testcase+'.rb'+' '+port
puts path
output = system('ruby #{path}') but it's getting stuck.. am recieving the parameter as class Login_test(port) and browser.goto "#{port}"

Comment: @Some_other_guy please open a separate question, it's a bit too much for a comment.

Comment: Sure, let me try a bit more. I fear for downvotes. :P

Answer (score 2):

Simply print it...

testcase.rb

```
...
print "passed"
```

testsuite.rb

```
...
output = `ruby testcase.rb` 
puts output #=> passed
...
```